# Windows 7 theme

Tags: windows-7, themes

I accidentally change my own theme into other theme. I right click on the desktop, then click personalize, in my screen, I've the current theme which denote by "Unsaved theme", then I click save theme, I named my theme into "Temaku", after that I change my theme into another theme, and then I changed it again into "Temaku". But, what I get is my windows color turns into windows classic, instead windows aero themes, now if I apply all my download theme like "Sasuke, Naruto theme" yes It's changed, but only for desktop background, not the taskbar (because it's on windows classic mode). How to get rid of these?

Answer (score 1):

eventhough all of you didn't answer my question, no problem. But, I've solved this, with my own method (I'm sure this method only familiar to me, but I hope it's familiar to you). Okay, the problem is "My taskbar theme didn't change everytime I changed my theme, but instead it turns into the new taskbar theme (let's say akatsuki theme), it turns into classic taskbar mode", The "theme" here is my downloaded theme, such as Naruto theme, Sasuke theme, etc. It's changed only in desktop background not on the taskbar, but I tell you that 3++ month ago, it does change my taskbar into "Akatsuki cloud, everytime I select one of those theme". Why this is happened? You know the uxtheme patcher, right? for the first time I apply this theme, it suggest me to patch 3 files : uxtheme.dll, themeui.dll, themeservice.dll, and after I patch that, then reboot, the taskbar theme has changed (denote by the akatsuki cloud on the taskbar). Now (today), I changed my theme once again, but the taskbar turns into classic, why the heck this is happened? I'm trying to figuring out, then I open the uxtheme patcher, what do I've found? the "themeui.dll" haven't patched, but actually I remember this have been patched. Okay, I patched it this time, then reboot, voila! my taskbar then changed. I assume there was my installed program, maybe when I updated Windows 7 to Service Pack 1, a while ago, which modifying this file into the new one (unpatched one). Thanks.